# Is there an easy way to make log4j smaller?

Tags: java, optimization, applet, log4j

I'd like to use log4j as a component in an applet, but at nearly half a megabyte, it's kind of big to be pushing out over the network. Is there any simple way of making it smaller? I don't need most of the appenders and things, and I'd really like to just strip out the ones I don't use, and include it in my jarfile as a "lite" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [`slf4j`](http://www.slf4j.org/)? If you're dealing with the plain aspects of `Logger` objects (aside from configuration), it's the same API, and it has a pluggable back-end, so the slf4j-simple-xxxx.jar would be a much smaller alternative than log4j with basically the same programming  interface.

Answer (score 1):

For an applet, I'm sure you don't need much beyond the standard logging api (included in the JRE so no download). You can also write your own [formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) to make it look more like log4j if you prefer.

Link here :: [Java Logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

My very simple idea is...

(1) Download log4j's source.
(2-a) Delete unused appender source.(ex. JDBCAppender.java)
(2-b) Delete xml package, if you not use xml function.
(2-c) Delete jmx package, if you not use jmx function.
(2-d) Delete chainsaw package, if you not use chainsaw function.
(2-e) Delete lf5 package, if you not use lf5 function.
(3) Delete generated error source.
(4) Export jar file.

Maybe, you can get quarter megabyte jar file. * But it is not to confirm action! *

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options: pack200, log4jmini (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/sandbox/log4j/log4jMini/trunk/) or tear it down to size yourself